# Create a new File Geodatabase(10.0) using data from existing Filegeodatabase(9.3)

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, file-geodatabase, error-000732, python-2.6

I want top create a new file geo-database using python, which I am able to do using arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(Fpath,"TestGDB","10.0")

But I want to transfer all data from an existing File geodatabse in ArcGIS 9.3 to this newly created geodatabase, what is the best way to do so using python?

I used  CopyFeatures_management(r"\Servername\Datafolder\Test.gdb","C:/Test/TEstGDB2.gdb")
but it gives me an error stating ERROR 000732: Input Features: Dataset\Servername\Datafolder\Test.gdb does not exist or is not supported

Comment: I don't think you are going to be able to copyfeatures using the database name. It is probably looking for either a feature dataset name or a feature class name. you would then have  to repeat for each feature class.

Comment: Hi brad, thanks for the reply, yes I think you are right it works this way, isnt there a way to copy all the whole file geodatabase all together like an extract function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend that you [copy the geodatabase](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000051000000) first

```
arcpy.Copy_management(r"\Servername\Datafolder\Test.gdb", "C:/Test/TestGDB2.gdb")
```

and then [upgrade the geodatabase](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000q7000000)

```
arcpy.UpgradeGDB_management("C:/Test/TestGDB2.gdb", "PREREQUISITE_CHECK", "UPGRADE")
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for the reply, I dont think it works this way I tried it, Copy_management still expects a feature class to feature class transfer

Comment: @GBh Copy and Copy Features (which you used in your question) are very different. Copy works with basically anything. If you really are having trouble with Copy, try adding "Workspace" as a third argument.

Comment: Thanks yeah it works using the copy_management, it creates a new GDB, copies everything including projection. Thanks a lot